# Google Cloud Windows Server 2019 VM snapshoot unable to boot

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform

I hope to find help with a problem I encountered by transferring some services to google cloud.

The problem concerns the ability to boot a disk created by a snapshoot of a windows server 2019 machine. I have not been able to boot a machine using one created by snapshoot as a disk.
I followed the google guide on removing the protection flags from the disk image by mounting it on another virtual machine, but the result I had was a KO anyway.

Without mounting the disk on a service machine to remove the flags, the windows console indicated an error (NO BOOT DEVICE). By carrying out the procedure described by google, the windows console CANNOT find the startup script, so the result is the same!

Procedures:

1. Create a snashoot of a windows server 2019 machine ON with VSS
2. Create a disk from the snapshot
3. Follow the guide go to this address to remove the read only flag (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot)

Remove the read-only flag from the disk
List all the volumes in the disk:

volume list
Select the new volume:

select volume [VOLUME_NUMBER]
Replace [VOLUME_NUMBER] with the volume that you need to configure for read / write.

Clear the read-only flag:

attr volume clear readonly hidden nodefaultdriveletter shadowcopy
Exit the diskpart tool:

exit
If the disk is a boot disk for another instance, sync the boot disk files with the new disk signature:

bcdboot [DRIVE_LETTER] Windows / s [DRIVE_LETTER]
Replace [DRIVE_LETTER] with the drive letter for the volume that you want to sync. For example, F: .

This procedure does NOT work. I have not been able to boot a disk created by no snapshoot, and this is a BIG problem for me. I await some information thanks

Comment: Is the boot disk formatted with MBR or UEFI? what is the output from `bcedit` from the original system and the new system? Edit your question with these details.

Comment: All Google virtual machine VM based on window server image run with UEFI

Comment: My question is how the boot disk is formatted. That depends on the original system and not how GCP creates new instances.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when a snapshot will not boot these means VSS is probably not functioning correctly and file system was not quiesced at the time of your snapshot.

You should try to mount the snapshot in another VM to determine if its in a consistent enough state to be read, assuming this is NTFS there is a very good chance it will be readable and it just has some issues booting (you can probably skip this step).

Assuming this is just a boot issue try these steps.

1. Boot from Windows Installation media.
2. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard, or an input method, and then click Next.
3. Click Repair your computer. (You could also try automated startup repair too.)
4. Select the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
5. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.

Proceed to read the article below to use bootrec.exe tool.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues-902ebb04-daa3-4f90-579f-0fbf51f7dd5d

Comment: Hi, I've try to create a snapshots with both setup: on windows server without windows vss agent and next with Microsoft vss agent (on the same VM) installed through server role. Google install an "hardware" recognised vss agent on default windows server 2019 image so I don't think this was related to vss , but I've tried to manual install from serve role. Same problem, snapshots from a running machine can't be booted selecting "vss snapshots" type from Google Cloud when created.
I can't boot with windows media on Google cloud platform , but I'm able to read and write disk mounted to other vm

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?